# Closing Selenium popup windows

Tags: python, selenium

I have Selenium and Chromedriver working to scrape text but it floods me with popup windows, Does anyone know how to automatically shut them when the code loops?
My code is:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time
i = 0
while i != 10:
    url = 'https://hytrack.me/'
    browser = webdriver.Chrome(r'C:\Users\kinet\OneDrive\Documents\webscraper\chromedriver.exe')
    browser.get(url)
    time.sleep(10)

    text = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="stat_totalPlayers"]').text
    print(text)
    i += 1
```

Comment: Try with chrome options

Comment: I don't understand why are you creating instance of webdriver, opening the web site and getting the text there again and again in the loop?

Comment: Also  get no pop-ups there...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can reuse the webdriver:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
import time

url = 'https://hytrack.me/'
browser = webdriver.Chrome(r'C:\Users\kinet\OneDrive\Documents\webscraper\chromedriver.exe')

i = 0
while i != 10:
    browser.get(url)
    time.sleep(10)

    text = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="stat_totalPlayers"]').text
    print(text)
    i += 1
```

You can also simplify the looping:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
import time

url = 'https://hytrack.me/'
browser = webdriver.Chrome(r'C:\Users\kinet\OneDrive\Documents\webscraper\chromedriver.exe')

for i in range(10):
    browser.get(url)
    time.sleep(10)
    text = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="stat_totalPlayers"]').text
    print(text)
```